# Netty Echo Server/Client - SSL doesn't work

Tags: ssl, netty

I want to add SSL to messages and I go to see the example of netty from [there](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/echo).

Ex: Echo Server

```
public final class EchoServer {

static final boolean SSL = System.getProperty("ssl") != null;
static final int PORT = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("port", "8007"));

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Configure SSL.
    final SslContext sslCtx;
    if (SSL) {
        SelfSignedCertificate ssc = new SelfSignedCertificate();
        sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forServer(ssc.certificate(), ssc.privateKey()).build();
    } else {
        sslCtx = null;}
```

I have some problems.
I don't realize the System.getProperty("ssl") what means? I test this code and get my "SSL" is null, why? I also use wireshark to fetch the connection, but didn't get ssl connection.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
static final boolean SSL = System.getProperty("ssl") != null;   
static final String HOST = System.getProperty("host", "127.0.0.1");   
static final int PORT = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("port", SSL? "8443" : "8080"));
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explaination

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable SSL in this example you should start it with "-Dssl" which will enable SSL for the example.

Netty itself also includes some scripts to make it easier when you checkout the source from git:

```
./run-example.sh -Dssl echo-server
./run-example.sh -Dssl echo-client
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use;

static final boolean SSL = true;

static final int PORT = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("port", SSL? "8443" : "8080"));

Resource Code: https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/helloworld